Problem with pct_change() method: ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
I'm trying to get the SP500 index returns of all US presidents but it seems something is going wrongly with the pct_change() method as I am not sure on how to 'discriminate' presidents for which there is no SP500 records.  Below you can see the code I'm trying to implement:
presidents['Start'] = presidents['Start'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%B %d, %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
presidents['End'] = presidents['End'][:-1].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%B %d, %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
presidents['End'].iloc[-1] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

cumulative_returns = {}
for index, row in presidents.iterrows():
    party = row['Party']
    president = row['Name']
    start_date = row['Start']
    end_date = row['End']
    sp500_data = yf.download('^GSPC', start_date, end_date, progress=False)['Adj Close']
    returns = sp500_data.pct_change()
    c_ret = (1 + returns).cumprod().fillna(axis=1)
    cumulative_returns[president] = {'cumulative_returns': c_ret, 'party': party}

This is what I get when executing the code:
 returns = sp500_data.pct_change()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

If someone could point out what is happening, it is highly appreciated.

Using iterrows is most likely not the good approach. Please provide a [mre] of your data and the matching expected output, and explain the logic.

I would assume that there is no data available for specified date range. Try to do something like this:
if sp500_data.empty:
    # Handle such a situation
else:
    returns = sp500_data.pct_change()


Thank you for your tip, it has solved my problem so far.  Next step would be to implement this script and visualize data in an Excel file.
